# Enthought Canopy No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, enthought, canopy

I can not open all my IPython notebook files in Enthought Canopy. I just used these files a couple of hours ago but then suddenly, an error occurs when I try to open the files.

The error says:

> Unable to open file 'C:\Users\user1\Python...
>   No JSON object could be decoded"

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Open Enthought Canopy
2. Click Editor
3. Drag and drop IPYNB file to tab.
4. Error always appear.

Please let me know how to fix this error.

Actions attempted to solve the problem:

1. Restart Enthought Canopy - Does not fix the problem
2. Restart PC - Does not fix the problem
3. Uninstall and Install newly downloaded installer - Does not fix the problem
4. Open the file on other computer - No Problem

Characteristics of my computer

1. Windows 7
2. 64 bit

Comment: What is the Canopy version? Did you modify the file on a different version of IPYthon? If you open a "Canopy Command Prompt" from the Start Menu, then "ipython notebook", can you open the same notebook file?

Comment: Hi Jonathan March,

Thank you very much for your inputs regarding "Canopy Command Prompt" --> "ipython notebook". I didn't know that you can open ipython notebook files in this method. Thanks for sharing this idea. Apparently, yes I was able to open the same notebook files. By the way, my Canopy version is 1.1.1.1452

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I did not modify the file on a different version of IPYthon.